# Product dictionary addition and subtraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, math, product

I need to write a function that accepts a dictionary as the inventory and also a product_list of (name, number) pairs which indicate when we should update the inventory of that product by adding a certain number to it which could be a negative number.

Once a product is mentioned for the first time it is added to the dictionary and when its count reaches zero it shold remain in the dictionary. If the count ever becomes negative I need to raise a value error.

Example:

```
d = {"apple":50, "pear":30, "orange":25}

ps = [("apple",20),("pear",-10),("grape",18)] 

shelve(d,ps)
d 
{'pear': 20, 'grape': 18, 'orange': 25, 'apple': 70}

shelve(d,[("apple",-1000)])
Traceback (most recent call last):

ValueError: negative amount for apple
```

My code is giving either an unexpected EOF error or invalid syntax depending on if I include the last print line. It is definitely not currently accomplishing the goal but I believe this is the format and somewhat the logic I'll need to solve this. I need the function to print 'negative amount for x' where x is the fruit that is negative. Any help on this is appreciated

Code:

```
def shelve(inventory,product_list):
    count = 0

try:

    for x in product_list:
        if x == True:
            product_list.append(x)
            count += key
        else:
            return product_list

except ValueError:
    print ('negative amount for (product)')   


print "hello program starts here"
d = {"apple":50, "pear":30, "orange":25}

ps = [("apple",20),("pear",-10),("grape",18)] 

shelve(d,ps)
```

Comment: python 3 requires you to use `print("string")`

Comment: Thanks just fixed that

Comment: Given the multitude of logic errors, you may require more help than you can get from Stack Overflow. This also looks like a homework question: I would seek additional help from your school if that's the case.

Comment: you set the parameters to empty dict and empty list after retrieving them. don't do that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: @Prune I did post my code and described the problem I understand that the logic is off though

Comment: I've tried correcting the obvious syntax errors in your code, but the closest I can come to reproducing a problem is to get a pair of **None** values.  I'm confused as to how you can get an unexpected EOF on this.  Please post an MCVE as I highlighted above.

Comment: @Prune Well after the edits someone helped make I'm now just getting return outside function which is probably referring to product_list I'll play around with it

Comment: That's the current problem.  It looks like the  try/except block is supposed to be part of **shelve**, but you placed it after the function instead of inside.  Indent those blocks?  As I've said, the code you posted does not produce the problems you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the important part of your task is to split your problem in sub problems. Using the dict and list data structure is mainly based on iterating over those data structures. Start simple and do one step at a time.So one way to solve the problem could be:

1.) Iterate over the product list (you can print the items to see what is happening). This will be the product loop.

```
for x in ps:
    print x
```

Check how you can access the lists elements with e.g. changing print x to print x[0] or x[1]

2.) Now for every product in the product loop, you need to iterate the inventory and set the inventory to the corresponding values. Start by just iterating the inventory and print its contents. Check out how it works before doing more complicated stuff, play around with it. ^^-d
(I just noticed there is a simpler solution than iterating, since its a dict, you will know what to do)

3.) Now add the Value error and Exception stuff

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation I'll see what I can do and post back later if I need further advice